# Viscous forces with asymmetric gradient velocity in fluid mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, viscosity

In fluid mechanics, the stress tensor writes $\sigma = -p 1 + \tau$ where the deviatoric part $\tau$ corresponds to shear. The viscous (volumic) forces are $\operatorname{div}\tau$.

For a Newtonian fluid, $\tau = \eta \dot\gamma$ where $\eta$ is the viscosity and $\dot\gamma$ is the shear rate.

As far as I understand, the shear rate is the velocity gradient $\nabla U$ which does not have to be symmetric (e.g. if vorticity is present).

I am confused with the fact that $\nabla U$ need not be symmetric while, physically, only the symmetric term contributes to viscosity/dissipation; the skew-symmetric terms of $\nabla U$ corresponds to rotation and do not "activate" viscosity. For this reasons, viscous forces are sometimes written $\eta(\nabla U + \nabla^\top U)/2$.

But then, the viscous forces for the skew-symmetric part should be 0, however the divergence of the skew-symmetric tensor is not 0 in general.

Can someone explain to me the exact relationship between the shear rate $\dot \gamma$ and the velocity gradient $\nabla U$?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of a material must be independent of the motion of any observer.  So, if an observer were rotating at the same angular velocity as the local vorticity, he would observe the same local rate of deformation tensor, but with the vorticity removed.  This would have to result in the same stress tensor, because the motion of the observer can not affect the stress.  This is why the anti-symmetric portion of the velocity gradient tensor must be removed in formulating a model to represent the stress tensor in terms of the kinematics of the motion.

Comment: This sounds sort of right, but I am not quite sure if the argument is entirely correct. A rotating observer is non-inertial (and may see funny forces). I think the correct version of this argument is that there should not be a stress in a rigidly rotating fluid, because this in an equilibrium state.

Comment: That's pretty much the same thing.  It doesn't matter if the observer is non-inertial as long as the fluid is inertial.  The stress tensor is what it is, and it doesn't change with a rotation of the observer.  The Principal of  Principal of Material Objectivity (aka the Principal of Material Frame Indifference) states that the mechanical  response of a material is independent of the translation and/or rotation of the observer.

Comment: Is that a known (valid?) principle of physics? If it is, it should follow from a symmetry of the laws of physics.

Comment: Yes, that is a known valid principle of physics, developed by the Continuum Mechanics guys at Johns Hopkins (in particular, Walter Noll) in the early '60s.  This was Clifford Truesdell's team at JH. At that time, the focus was on developing valid constitutive equations to describe the thermomechanical behavior of viscoelastic materials.   Google it, and see what comes up.  As far as it following from a symmetry law of physics, symmetry laws are not part of my background.

Comment: That's interesting -- I was unaware of this. Some googling shows that there was (and maybe still is) an argument between Truedell, Noll, and others and various members of the physics community about whether such a principle exist. For some particularly nasty comments about Truesdell see Ingo Muller "A History of Thermodynamics."

Comment: To me, the point is this: Why would we expect the equation of continuum (fluid) mechanics to form-invariant (covariant) under rotations, given that the laws of mechanics are not?

Comment: They're not invariant under rotations.  They're invariant under **rotations of the observer**.   I thought I made that clear.

Comment: Yes, but Newton's equations are not invariant under rotations of the observer. A rotating observer sees a Coriolis force, a non-rotating observer does not.

Comment: A rotating observer experiences a coriolis force personally, but he can have no effect on the state of stress in a liquid or solid.  The stress tensor in the body is what it is, irrespective of the motion of any observer.

Comment: How can a passive observer affect the state of stress in a material?

Comment: You keep saying this, but that's not a physical argument. If the microscopic laws of physics look different to an inertial and a rotating observer, why would the laws of fluid dynamics look the same (which is what this principle asserts)?

Comment: @Thomas  I'm obviously having trouble explaining this, so I'm going to have to withdraw from our discussion.  Please don't take it personally.

Comment: If you want to ponder this further; Take a look at the book by Muller that I found using google (mentioned above). In Insert 8.1 he provides am example for the frame dependence of heat flux which (I think) is completely correct.

Comment: From Truesdell's Wiki page:  "Müller's words regarding Truesdell, however, should be taken with a grain of salt. An article written by Müller ("On the frame dependence of stress and heat flux," Arch. Ration. Mech. Anal. 45, 241 (1972)) was strongly refuted by Truesdell ("Correction of two errors in the kinetic theory of gases which have been used to cast unfounded doubt upon the principle of material frame-indifference," Meccanica 4, 196 (1976)), and it appears that Müller never forgot the incident."

Comment: To me, wikipedia pages like this one
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectivity_%28frame_invariance%29
illustrate the problem. The page states what "frame invariance of
material response" is, but not why we expect it to be true. Muller
(for all his faults) actually gives an explicit argument why we
don't expect it to be true.

Comment: I should explain why I am so insistent on this point. I have written 
a number of papers (such as this one http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.6843)
in which I compute transport coefficients using a variety of microscopic
theories. The results violate "frame invariance" (although I had 
not heard of this concept when I wrote them). That's not a surprise,
because "frame invariance" is not a property of Newton's equation, 
or the Boltzmann equation, or quantum field theory.

Comment: I've looked over the abstract, but what you've done is way outside my background.  Sorry.  Wish I could help you resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Let me write $\Pi=\nabla\cdot u$. The shear strain is given by
$$
 S_{ij}=\nabla_iu_j+\nabla_ju_i-\frac{2}{3}\delta_{ij}\Pi
$$
and the vorticity tensor is
$$
\Omega_{ij}=\nabla_iu_j-\nabla_ju_i .
$$
The most general stress tensor linear in gradients of $u$ is
$$
\tau_{ij} = \eta S_{ij} + \zeta \delta_{ij} \Pi + \eta_R \Omega_{ij}.
$$
We want to show that $\eta_R=0$.

1) The most general argument (I think) was given here [In a fluid, why are the shear stresses $\tau_{xy}$ and $\tau_{yx}$ equal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187044/in-a-fluid-why-are-the-shear-stresses-tau-xy-and-tau-yx-equal/187047#187047) . The stress tensor must be symmetric for angular momentum to be conserved (so we can view it as a consequence of rotational symmetry).

1b) A (somewhat) more physical argument is this: In a rigidly rotating fluid, we don't expect any dissipative stresses (as this is an equilibrium state).

2) I think the argument that $\nabla_i\omega_i=0$ is not relevant. The divergence of the vorticity vector is not the same $\nabla_i$ on $\Omega_{ij}$ (the latter is related to the curl of the curl $u$).

3) In general there is nothing wrong with $\Omega$ appearing in the stress tensor. If I go beyond linear order (non-Newtonian fluids), then terms like $\Omega_{ik}\Omega^k_j$ and $S_{ik}\Omega^k_j$ can (and do) appear.

4) Finally, microscopic expressions for $T_{ij}$ are manifestly symmetric. In kinetic theory 
$$T_{ij}= \frac{1}{m}\int d^3p\, p_i p_j \,f(x,p).$$
In quantum field theory the symmetry of the stress tensor is a little subtle, but once we couple to gravity, we have
$$
 T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}},
$$
which is manifestly symmetric.